# C++ Java static final equivalent

Tags: c++, static, constants, declaration

I am using C++ to program a chess game. I want to create two class attributes for the class Board: ROWS and COLUMNS. In Java, I would declare they as static final and everything would work as I want. How I do the same declaration in C++? I need to access these attributes by "Board::ROWS" and "Board::COLUMNS" in other classes.

What I have is this, which is throwing compilation errors since ROWS and COLUMNS are not declared in the scope of the declaration of m_TileMap. Is there a good practice for doing this without using **#define** statement?

```
class Board {
  Tile *m_TileMap[ROWS][COLUMNS];

public:
  static const int ROWS = 8;
  static const int COLUMNS = 8;

  Board(int m[ROWS][COLUMNS]);
}
```

Comment: I suggest using std::vector<int> instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

declare your m_TileMap after the declaration of ROWS and COLUMNS

e.g.

```
class Board {

public:
  static const int ROWS = 8;
  static const int COLUMNS = 8;

  Board(int m[ROWS][COLUMNS]);

private:
  Tile *m_TileMap[ROWS][COLUMNS];
};
```

The reason for this is because in C++, the compiler does not read forward. So in order for `ROWS` and `COLUMNS` to be understood by the compiler when you declare m_TileMap, they need to be declared before.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-order the class members, so that ROWS and COLUMNS are declared before they're used:

```
class Board {
public:
  static const int ROWS = 8;
  static const int COLUMNS = 8;

  Board(int m[ROWS][COLUMNS]);

private: 
  Tile *m_TileMap[ROWS][COLUMNS];
};
```

Comment: @LucasKreutz - You're welcome. And welcome to StackOverflow. You can upvote answers you find useful by clicking the up-triangle to their left. (This is available in addition to check-marking the answer most useful to you.)

Answer (score 1):

Try use enums as following

```
class Board {
public:
    enum {ROWS = 8};
    enum {COLUMNS = 8};

private:
    Tile *m_TileMap[ROWS][COLUMNS];

public:
    Board(int m[ROWS][COLUMNS]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`ROWS` and `COLUMNS` have not yet been declared when the definition for `m_TileMap` is parsed.  Simply move those definitions:

```
class Board {
  Tile *m_TileMap[ROWS][COLUMNS];

public:
  static const int ROWS = 8;
  static const int COLUMNS = 8;

  Board(int m[ROWS][COLUMNS]);
};
```

As an aside, if you don't need to ever take the address of `ROWS` or `COLUMNS`, an alternative would be to use an `enum`, like this:

```
class Board {
public:
  enum { ROWS = 8, COLUMNS = 8};
  Tile *m_TileMap[ROWS][COLUMNS];


  Board(int m[ROWS][COLUMNS]);
};
```

All this having been said, wouldn't life be so much simpler if you just used `vector`?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll use an enum, I think it's pretty better. I used an array cause I think it will be easier to use with a minimax algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to state the sizes in the class definition:

```
static const int ROWS = 8;
// etc.
```

And don't forget the `;` after the class definition!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `#define` which is more C-style but also more performant than enums. The reason, why this is the fastest is that the compiler replaces every instance of eg `ROW` with the actual calue (8).
Furthermore, the Java compiler also replaces `static final`-variables to the actual byte code (which can sometimes be a problem, [see here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-syntax-for-declaring-a-static-final-class-variable))

In your example that would be:

```
#define ROWS 8;
#define COLUMNS 8;
class Board {
public:
  Board(int m[ROWS][COLUMNS]);
private:
  Tile *m_TileMap[ROWS][COLUMNS];
};
```

But be aware of the visibilities and the adress space - you shouldn't put definitions like the in the header, because you would then force them upon everybody.

For the header, this would be preferred: Let's say you have a header file (board.h) in which you specify

```
class Board {
public:
  static const int ROWS = 8;
  static const int COLUMNS = 8;
  //...
};
```

So everybody including your board.h can use `Board::ROWS` and `Board::COLUMNS`. (this is intended behavior)
See [this answer for reference](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/454265-convert-static-final-java-c#post1738052).

Another difference worth mentioning is that these makros are untyped in comparison to `const`, which is typed (has type int for example while the defined value has none). Additionally, there are also dynamic constants, but that should be a bit too far off topic - [further reading here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)#Dynamically-valued_constants).
But also the defines in C/C++ can do much more, [see here for example](https://www.quora.com/What-is-are-the-alternative-s-of-define-in-java).

Another thing a bit prospective: the constant strings **[C++ equivalent of Java static final String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636336/c-equivalent-of-java-static-final-string?lq=1)** (first answer)